# Is this $string[1] valid PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have coded in PHP for over 10 years and this is the first time I have come across this (legacy code base):

```
$string = "123456789";
$new_number = $string[1]
```

$new_number is now 2.

Am I going crazy?  I never knew you could add to a string with [x].

EDIT:  As many have pointed out,  strings in PHP are stored as an array of characters.  However,  I am right in thinking this is quite unique to PHP?  Could you do this in a strongly typed language like C++/C#/Java?

Comment: No, you're not going crazy.

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this with most high level languages.

Comment: Not sure why I am being down voted to oblivion.  Pretty rude tbh, it is a genuine question around PHP's behavior.

Comment: For extra credit, try `$new_number = $string{1};`

Comment: No, it is not unique to PHP. It is basic for low level languages. And PHP syntax have some similarities with C .

Comment: I don't think people are just downvoting you to be rude. This question is easily answered by simply looking at language specifications. SO isn't really a place to post a 'Wow, look at what I just learned' post. And as tier1 mentioned, this is fairly common in almost all languages such as PHP, c/c++/c#/etc... since strings are usually simply arrays of chars.

Comment: @EquinoxMatt So where are we with this question now?

Comment: @gmiley I understand that,  but I did have a look around and couldn't find a clear reference to it.  Maybe I was looking in the wrong place.  Maybe I didn't know because this is something I have never come across before.  It wouldn't ever even cross my mind to use a string in that manner.  However down voting this question simply means whoever else comes across the same issue will have to look elsewhere for the answer.  My question is structured well enough to people to answer it.  

I always though the up vote /down vote was to control quality of the question, not if you like it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't got crazy. You can access any string within PHP as it would be an array and access each character individual. As you can see here in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in **$str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose**. [...]

Answer (score 1):

Because a string is effective an array of char's in PHP. This means that you can individually get the characters by accessing the right index. This isnt adding anything really, its just fetching the second character of the string which is '2'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You are not crazy. In PHP you can access the characters in a string by their index. It's treated a lot like an array. You cannot add to the string with `$string[]` as you would an array, but you can change the value to another character.

```
$string = "test";
$string[1] = "s";
echo $string; // Echoes 'tsst'
```